# How to explicitly define the return type of a generic returned class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have code like this:

```
import * as events from 'events' // Node.js events module

// my own version of EventEmitter with better typing
interface IEventEmitter<EventTypes> { /* ... */ }

// eslint-disable-next-line typescript/explicit-function-return-type
export function EventEmitter<EventTypes>() {
  // merge the IEventEmitter interface and EventEmitter as IEventEmitter
  // implementation into one.
  // XXX Is there a better way?
  return class NewEventEmitter
    extends ((events.EventEmitter as unknown) as IEventEmitter<EventTypes>)
    implements IEventEmitter<EventTypes> {}
}
```

As you can see I disabled an eslint rule so that it doesn't complain that I haven't specified the return type, and I let the return type be inferred.

But, how ***would*** I write that return type?

EDIT: Here's a [playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20import%20%7BEventEmitter%20as%20NodeEventEmitter%7D%20from%20'events'%0Adeclare%20const%20NodeEventEmitter%3A%20any%20%2F%2F%20%5E%0A%0Atype%20EventTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SOME_EVENT%3A%20number%0A%20%20%20%20OTHER_EVENT%3A%20string%0A%20%20%20%20ANOTHER_EVENT%3A%20undefined%20%2F%2F%20undefined%20means%20this%20event%20will%20have%20no%20payload%0A%20%20%20%20READONLY_EVENT%3A%20ReadonlyArray%3Cnumber%3E%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20EventArgs%3CEventTypes%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20EventTypes%3E%20%3D%20EventTypes%5BK%5D%20extends%20undefined%20%3F%20%5B%5D%20%3A%20%5BEventTypes%5BK%5D%5D%0A%0Ainterface%20IEventEmitter%3CEventTypes%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20new%20()%3A%20IEventEmitter%3CEventTypes%3E%0A%20%20%20%20on%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20EventTypes%3E(s%3A%20K%2C%20listener%3A%20(...v%3A%20EventArgs%3CEventTypes%2CK%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20emit%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20EventTypes%3E(s%3A%20K%2C%20...v%3A%20EventArgs%3CEventTypes%2CK%3E)%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20makeEventEmitterClass%3CEventTypes%3E()%3A%20typeof%20NewEventEmitter%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20merge%20the%20IEventEmitter%20interface%20and%20EventEmitter%20as%20IEventEmitter%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20implementation%20into%20one.%0A%20%20return%20class%20NewEventEmitter%0A%20%20%20%20extends%20((NodeEventEmitter%20as%20unknown)%20as%20IEventEmitter%3CEventTypes%3E)%0A%20%20%20%20implements%20IEventEmitter%3CEventTypes%3E%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20EventEmitter%20%3D%20makeEventEmitterClass%3CEventTypes%3E()%0Aconst%20emitter%20%3D%20new%20EventEmitter%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20GOOD%3A%0Aemitter.on('SOME_EVENT'%2C%20(payload)%20%3D%3E%20testNumber(payload))%3B%0Aemitter.on('OTHER_EVENT'%2C%20(payload)%20%3D%3E%20testString(payload))%3B%0Aemitter.emit('SOME_EVENT'%2C%2042)%0Aemitter.emit('OTHER_EVENT'%2C%20'foo')%0A%0Adeclare%20function%20testNumber(value%3A%20number)%3A%20void%0Adeclare%20function%20testString(value%3A%20string)%3A%20void%0A) that shows @KarolMajewski's answer isn't working for me. It says `Cannot find name 'NewEventEmitter'. Did you mean 'NodeEventEmitter'?`.

EDIT 2: @KarolMajewski's answer does indeed work. For it to work, the class has to be assigned to a local variable. Here's the [playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20import%20%7BEventEmitter%20as%20NodeEventEmitter%7D%20from%20'events'%0Adeclare%20const%20NodeEventEmitter%3A%20any%20%2F%2F%20%5E%0A%0Atype%20EventTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SOME_EVENT%3A%20number%0A%20%20%20%20OTHER_EVENT%3A%20string%0A%20%20%20%20ANOTHER_EVENT%3A%20undefined%20%2F%2F%20undefined%20means%20this%20event%20will%20have%20no%20payload%0A%20%20%20%20READONLY_EVENT%3A%20ReadonlyArray%3Cnumber%3E%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20EventArgs%3CEventTypes%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20EventTypes%3E%20%3D%20EventTypes%5BK%5D%20extends%20undefined%20%3F%20%5B%5D%20%3A%20%5BEventTypes%5BK%5D%5D%0A%0Ainterface%20IEventEmitter%3CEventTypes%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20new%20()%3A%20IEventEmitter%3CEventTypes%3E%0A%20%20%20%20on%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20EventTypes%3E(s%3A%20K%2C%20listener%3A%20(...v%3A%20EventArgs%3CEventTypes%2CK%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20emit%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20EventTypes%3E(s%3A%20K%2C%20...v%3A%20EventArgs%3CEventTypes%2CK%3E)%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20makeEventEmitterClass%3CEventTypes%3E()%3A%20typeof%20NewEventEmitter%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20merge%20the%20IEventEmitter%20interface%20and%20EventEmitter%20as%20IEventEmitter%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20implementation%20into%20one.%0A%20%20const%20NewEventEmitter%20%3D%20class%20extends%20((NodeEventEmitter%20as%20unknown)%20as%20IEventEmitter%3CEventTypes%3E)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20implements%20IEventEmitter%3CEventTypes%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20return%20NewEventEmitter%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20EventEmitter%20%3D%20makeEventEmitterClass%3CEventTypes%3E()%0Aconst%20emitter%20%3D%20new%20EventEmitter%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20GOOD%3A%0Aemitter.on('SOME_EVENT'%2C%20(payload)%20%3D%3E%20testNumber(payload))%3B%0Aemitter.on('OTHER_EVENT'%2C%20(payload)%20%3D%3E%20testString(payload))%3B%0Aemitter.emit('SOME_EVENT'%2C%2042)%0Aemitter.emit('OTHER_EVENT'%2C%20'foo')%0A%0Adeclare%20function%20testNumber(value%3A%20number)%3A%20void%0Adeclare%20function%20testString(value%3A%20string)%3A%20void%0A).

Comment: Use [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) to see the inferred type and then copy it manually to the return type annotation?  (Someone with node.js events installed can probably tell you more explicitly)

Comment: @jcalz It'd be awesome if that worked. The intellisense is telling me to do exactly that, which leads to effectively the same thing Karol Majewski told me to do in that answer, and I've update the question with a playground link that shows that that isn't working.

Comment: oh, I see, it's using some name from an inner scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between writing explicit return types and letting TypeScript infer their type, there is a third way:

```
import * as events from 'events';

interface IEventEmitter<EventTypes> { /* ... */ }

export function EventEmitter<EventTypes>(): typeof MyClass {
  const MyClass = class extends events.EventEmitter implements IEventEmitter<EventTypes> {};

  return MyClass;
}
```

Although it's a bit of a trick, and it requires what's called an *unnecessary local variable*. In this case, this variable (`MyClass`) is used only to read type from.

Comment: I wish that worked. Check out the playground example I added to my question to show that it doesn't work. It says `Cannot find name 'NewEventEmitter'. Did you mean 'NodeEventEmitter'?`.

Comment: This looks like it works to me.   Your playground example isn't using the `const NewEventEmitter = class extends` syntax as this answer suggests.  Fix it and it should work.

Comment: @jcalz is correct — you forgot to assign `NewEventEmitter` to a local variable before returning it. It should say `const NewEventEmitter = class extends /* ... */`, and then `return NewEventEmitter;`.

Comment: You're right, that works! Added playground link to my question. But it doesn't make sense how the inner scope can seem to go to the seemingly outside. In other words, I would've thought that the return type can only be specified from types that are in the outer scope.

Comment: I am unable to get this to work in one project, which is using TypeScript `3.3.0-dev.20181129`. I copy the exact code from the working example I added to the question above, but on the `typeof NewEventEmitter` it complains "Return type of exported function has or is using private name 'NewEventEmitter'". Any ideas? I am generating declaration files. Maybe it is encountering the following problem? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6307

Answer (score 0):

Declare the return type to be `IEventEmitter<EventTypes>`

```
function makeEventEmitterClass<EventTypes>(): IEventEmitter<EventTypes> {
  // merge the IEventEmitter interface and EventEmitter as IEventEmitter
  // implementation into one.
  return class NewEventEmitter
    extends ((NodeEventEmitter as unknown) as IEventEmitter<EventTypes>)
    implements IEventEmitter<EventTypes> {}
}
```

Comment: I thought that too, but it breaks how declaration exports/imports work.